# Creating a Pop-Up Calendar in a VSTO Excel Project

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, excel, vsto

I'm trying to use the System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar control within a VSTO Excel workbook. I want the MonthCalendar to pop up when I click a button in the ribbon, but so far I can't get the control to display at all.

```
Private Sub DeliveryDateFromCalendarButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles DeliveryDateFromCalendarButton.Click
    Dim selectedFiscalYear As String = Me.FiscalYearDropDown.SelectedItem.Label
    Dim cal As System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar = New System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar()

    cal.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
    cal.Show()
End Sub
```

The calendar should pop up at the place they clicked, but alas, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new System.Windows.Form and adding my calendar to its Controls collection.

Not ideal, so I'm still looking for a solution, but it at least gets me a pop-up calendar.

Comment: I think he means he ended up just having a button click that did a Form.Show and had the calendar on that, as opposed to directly from the ribbon which is possible I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you need a form in order to host a winforms control.
If your goal was to have "just" the calender control appear by itself then what would the parent window be?

If you want the "appearance" of just a calender control that is easy enough, just tweak the UI properties of the form so that it has no visible border, is modal, etc, if you rewrite in WPF then your form doesn't even have to look like a form (i.e. square etc)